# Javascript - How to get contents of elements without ids

Tags: javascript, jquery, getelementbyid, getelementsbyclassname

http://jsfiddle.net/n253R/3/

right check the above.

I want to have the numbers change color based on the number. There will be a lot of these as they will be part of different posts on Wordpress. At the moment i can only effect one how can I can effect them all.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    var scorePerformance = document.getElementById("performance").textContent;
    console.log(scorePerformance);
    if(scorePerformance >= 9){
        jQuery('#performance').css('color', 'red');
    } else if (scorePerformance >= 8 && scorePerformance < 9 ){
        jQuery('#performance').css('color', 'orange');
    } else if (scorePerformance >= 6 && scorePerformance < 8){
        jQuery('#performance').css('color', 'yellow');
    } else {
        jQuery('#performance').css('color', 'blue');
    } 

    var scoreSongwriting = document.getElementById("songwriting").textContent;
    if(scoreSongwriting >= 9){
        jQuery('#songwriting').css('color', 'red');
    } else if (scoreSongwriting >= 8 && scoreSongwriting < 9 ){
        jQuery('#songwriting').css('color', 'orange');
    } else if (scoreSongwriting >= 6 && scoreSongwriting < 8){
        jQuery('#songwriting').css('color', 'yellow');
    }  else {
        jQuery('#songwriting').css('color', 'blue');
    } 

    var scoreProduction = document.getElementById("production").textContent;
    if(scoreProduction >= 9){
        jQuery('#production').css('color', 'red');
    } else if (scoreProduction >= 8 && scoreProduction < 9 ){
        jQuery('#production').css('color', 'orange');
    } else if (scoreProduction >= 6 && scoreProduction < 8){
        jQuery('#production').css('color', 'yellow');
    }  else {
        jQuery('#production').css('color', 'blue');
    } 

    var scoreBonus = document.getElementById("bonus").textContent;
    if(scoreBonus >= 9){
        jQuery('#bonus').css('color', 'red');
    } else if (scoreBonus >= 8 && scoreBonus < 9 ){
        jQuery('#bonus').css('color', 'orange');
    } else if (scoreBonus >= 6 && scoreBonus < 8){
        jQuery('#bonus').css('color', 'yellow');
    }  else {
        jQuery('#bonus').css('color', 'blue');
    } 

    var scoreFinal = document.getElementById("final").textContent;
    if(scoreFinal >= 9){
        jQuery('#final').css('color', 'red');
    } else if (scoreFinal >= 8 && scoreFinal < 9 ){
        jQuery('#final').css('color', 'orange');
    } else if (scoreFinal >= 6 && scoreFinal < 8){
        jQuery('#final').css('color', 'yellow');
    }  else {
        jQuery('#final').css('color', 'blue');
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mome's answer is correct that you should use class instead of ID for selecting/differentiating multiple elements. But if you still need to use ID do it like following

```
$("[id=performance]").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var scorePerformance = $this.val();
    if(scorePerformance >= 9){
        $this.css('color', 'red');
    } else if (scorePerformance >= 8 && scorePerformance < 9 ){
        $this.css('color', 'orange');
    } else if (scorePerformance >= 6 && scorePerformance < 8){
        $this.css('color', 'yellow');
    } else {
        $this.css('color', 'blue');
    } 
});
```

I have updated fiddle with above code here http://jsfiddle.net/Gem32/1/

You can use [contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) if you need exact match.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n253R/4/

Change your list item to have a class, not an ID as an ID should be unique:

```
<li class="bonus">10</li>
```

Then use jquery's each() function eg:

```
  jQuery('.bonus').each(function(){
    var scoreBonus = $(this).text();
    if(scoreBonus >= 9){
    jQuery(this).css('color', 'red');
    } else if (scoreBonus >= 8 && scoreBonus < 9 ){
    jQuery(this).css('color', 'orange');
    } else if (scoreBonus >= 6 && scoreBonus < 8){
    jQuery(this).css('color', 'yellow');
    }  else {
    jQuery(this).css('color', 'blue');
    }     
});
```

Comment: the selector should be `$(".scores").children()` instead of $(".bonus")

Comment: You are correct, that will only require a single function instead of 4.

Answer (score 1):

If the number's are limited (i.e. more like 1..10 than 1..1000), you could use this:

```
$('li:contains(6)').css('color', 'yellow');
$('li:contains(7)').css('color', 'red');
$('li:contains(8)').css('color', 'green');
$('li:contains(9)').css('color', 'blue');
$('li:contains(10)').css('color', 'orange');
```

This makes it quite readable, it's easy to figure out which color is assigned to which number.

You can make it even more explicit (or even fetch this mapping from some API/database):

```
var mapping = {
  '6': 'yellow',
  '7': 'red',
  '8': 'green',
  '9': 'blue',
  '10': 'orange'
};

for (var i in mapping) {
  if (mapping.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
    $('li:contains(' + i + ')').css('color', mapping[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: I think in his scenario your solution will also work as it is only a score out of 10

Comment: Wasn't me, but `:contains` is no longer a supported pseudo-class: http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#content-selectors It should **not** be used.

Comment: @AymanSafadi - question is about jQuery, and there it's still supported and isn't even depreceated, I think.

Answer (score 1):

some suggestions:

- when selecting multiple times the same element cache that in a variable, not only it will look more clean, but it will be faster as well
- `document.getElementById("ID")` equals to `jQuery('#ID')` only the latter is wrapped by jQuery
- when applying the same method multiple times with just different parameters based on some logic, you can store the value inside a variable and call the method only once
- since you're using jQuery use `.text()` instead of `.textContent` so it'll work crossbrowser
- you can work on collection as well as single elements, in fact jQuery provide a nice `each` function which will simplify your code a lot

As for the solution of your problem you can reuse the generic class 'scores' you already have
and use `jQuery(".scores li")` as the selector. so applying all my suggestion above you'll end up with this code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var scores = jQuery('.scores li')
    scores.each(function(index){
        var score = jQuery(this)
        var value = score.text()
        var color = 'blue'
        if(value >= 9){
            color = 'red'
        } else if (value >= 8 && value < 9 ){
            color = 'orange'
        } else if (value >= 6 && value < 8){
            color = 'yellow'
        }
        score.css('color', color)        
    })
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kentaromiura/n253R/5/